# How add an Object to this JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have this JSON in a File:

```
{
  "user1": {
    "id": 1,
    "nVote": 0,
    "comment": ""
  }
}
```

And I would like to add an object user2 with the same parameters and corresponding values.

```
function json2Array(json) {
  var result = [];
  var keys = Object.keys(json);
  keys.forEach(function (key) {
    result.push(json[key]);
  });
  return result;
}

const fs = require('fs');
const obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./datei.json', 'utf8'));
const arObj = json2Array(obj);

let user = [];
user['user2'] = {
  "id": 2,
  "nVote": 1,
  "comment": 'test'
};

arObj.push(user);
```

that result:

```
    [
      { id: 1, nVote: 0, comment: '' },
      [ user2: { id: 2, nVote: 1, comment: 'test' } ]
    ]
```

But I would like to ultimately this result:

```
    {
      "user1": { id: 1, nVote: 0, comment: '' },
      "user2": { id: 2, nVote: 1, comment: 'test' }
    }
```

Comment: Your `json2Array()` function is the same as the built-in `Object.values()` function.

Comment: `arObj` is not an array, you are already getting the _object_ you want out of JSON.parse. So don't convert it to an array, just keep it the way it is and simply add your `"user2"` property/value pair. Why did you add all this extra code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result you want is an object, there's no need to convert it to an array. Just add a property to the object.

```
const obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./datei.json', 'utf8'));
obj['user2'] = {
  "id": 2,
  "nVote": 1,
  "comment": 'test'
};
```

Comment: @StephenQuan Probably one of the people who downvoted the question -- they think you shouldn't answer bad questions.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to treat the json object as array

simply

consider this

```json
[
{user1:{"id":2,"nVote":1,...}}
{user2:{"id":2,"nVote":1,...}}
]
```

so

```
const obj = []
obj.push({user1:{id:2,nVote:2})
obj.push(({user2:{id:3,nVote:1})
```

that's all you need then you can store that using the fs to extract it to a json file

Comment: in case you want to append it to an existing file, all you have to do is append the JSON file in form of a array by using `JSON.parse()`
but the json file should have [content] to treat it as an array

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't want at all.

Comment: can you give a clear explain what you want